# I recieved and error while installing browseVignette("packagename") in R, what do I do?

Tags: r, package, vignette

I'm very new to R and recently installed R-studio. I'm trying to familiarize myself with packages by using browseVignettes() but it returning error as

{unexpected input in "browseVignettes(“" }

or

{in find.package(package, lib.loc) :
there is no package called ‘packagename’}.

What do i do?

Tried to input the code over and over but no result. I have no knowledge of what the error may be.

Comment: Run `install.package("packagename")` then try `browseVignettes("packagename")` again.